# New-PSDrive not visible to other shells contrary to MS documentation

Tags: azure, powershell, smb, new-psdrive

I've been trying al sorts of varieties of the following, trying to mount a network share in such a way it can be visible for **both** other shells and in *File Explorer*. According to the MS documentation of the related commands, saying one can use `-Persistent` and `-Scope Global` to make them "immediately visible to other shells", it just doesn't work.

```
$mDL       = 'Z'        # Mount to this Drive Letter
$dDesc     = 'ML-DATA'  # Description of PSDrive
$NLRoot    = "\\somepath.windows.net\xxx"
$UserName  = "localhost\someuser"

$cred = Get-Credential -Credential $UserName

New-PSDrive -Name $mDL -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root $NLRoot -Credential $cred -Description $dDesc -Persist -Scope Global
```

The data container is in Azure, and everything seem to work apart from being visible from other parts in my system (Win10).

**How can I make this drive visible from other `PowerShell` instances and *File Explorer*?**

---

**UPDATE**: `2022-07-06`

My bad, the text was from the *ss64* docs for [New-SmbMapping](https://ss64.com/ps/new-smbmapping.html), where it was stated:

> When a drive mapping is created with New-SmbMapping the new drive will not be visible to any currently running processes (including Windows Explorer) until that process is restarted (or the machine is rebooted). **The one exception to this is the PowerShell console, all PowerShell sessions on the machine will immediately get the new drive mappings.**

It may also be that the MS documentation is not easily understood by non-specialists, because in the [New-PSDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.2) docs, the following is stated in 2 places.

- In `Example-4`:
  *The mapped drive can be viewed on the local computer in PowerShell sessions, File Explorer, and with tools such as net use.*
- In the `Paramters` list under `-Persist`:
  *Mapped network drives are saved in Windows on the local computer. They're persistent, not session-specific, and can be viewed and managed in File Explorer and other tools.*

---

So how can I make this share *user* and *session type* agnostic, in such a way that `Z:` is visible "everywhere" and for "everyone" in both in *File Explorer* and whatever powershell/cmd they want to use?

---

**Useful References**:

- https://www.bloggingforlogging.com/2018/11/22/windows-mapped-drives-what-the-hell-is-going-on/
- https://activedirectorypro.com/map-network-drives-with-group-policy/

Comment: Are you running PowerShell as an administrator?

Comment: The New-PSDrive docs *never* say the drive will be visible by "other shells". `-Scope Global` means the drive will be visible outside the script's local scope

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm guessing that quote is from non-PowerShell docs, given that establishing persistent drive mappings is not a PowerShell feature (only surfaced via `New-PSDrive`). And the quote _does_ apply, with the following constraints: By default, a mapping is immediately visible to all other shells created _by the same user_ AND if those shells have the _same session type_ (regular (non-elevated) vs. elevated (run as admin)). However, a system can be configured to make them visible  irrespective of session type.

Comment: The word `shell` [doesn't even exist in the command docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.2) and would be a very weird term to use in official documentation because it's a term used in the console subsystem. Other shells are Bash and zsh. The docs talk about sessions. I suspect that's what the OP is actually talking about. Even `console` would be inaccurate, because applications can create their own PS sessions in code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, a persistent drive mapping _has nothing to do with PowerShell_, PowerShell just facilitates its creation, as `net.exe use` and File Explorer do. I have no idea where the quote came from, perhaps not2qubit paraphrased - it ultimately isn't that important.  Yes, the word _processes_ would have been better. A more pertinent interpretation of "other shells" is other shell _sessions_, _irrespective of what shell binary underlies them_ (`cmd.exe`, PowerShell, ...). I've added a clarification re shell vs. processes to my answer; let me know if you think something is missing/wrong

Comment: Would it be possible using [`New-SmbShare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbshare?view=windowsserver2022-ps) or [`New-SmbMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbmapping?view=windowsserver2022-ps)? (TBH, I'm not exactly sure what the difference is between these 3?)

Comment: There's [`New-SmbGlobalMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbglobalmapping), whose help states (emphasis added): "creates an SMB global mapping on the SMB client to an SMB share. Global mappings _allow all users to use the same mapping. Its primary use is for Windows Containers_." Not sure about the container angle. As for `New-SmbShare` vs. `New-SmbMapping`: the former is used on the _server_ to create a share that _clients_ can connect to; the latter is used on a _client_ to map a drive letter to a server's share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm not sure if Azure-specific considerations apply*, but, generally speaking:

**tl;dr**

**"Immediately visible to all other shells"** with respect to newly established persistent drive mappings applies to:

- **By default**: Shell processes (such as PowerShell and `cmd.exe` sessions) - more generally, (native) processes *in general* - that were created:

  - by the **same user** *and*
  - have the ***same session type***: *regular* (non-elevated) vs. *elevated* (run as admin).
- ***If* your system is configured accordingly** (see below): Processes that were created:

  - by the **same user**
  - *irrespective* of session type.

Note: All the information in this answer **also applies to *non-persistently* mapped drives, assuming they are established with *system-level* features, such as `net.exe use` or File Explorer. PowerShell does *not* allow you to create such mappings**: if you omit `-Persist` in a `New-PSDrive` call, you'll get an (always non-persistent, session-specific and possibly scope-specific) *PowerShell-only* drive.

---

**Persistently mapped network drives are *user-specific***:

- *As is to be expected*, *other* users won't see a given user's persistently mapped drives.
- *Surprisingly*, **even in the context of the *same* user, trying to establish a persistent drive *from an elevated session* (run as administrator) does *not* work**: the request to make the mapping *persistent* is quietly ignored (that is, the mapping is quietly **only established for the *current* session and only visible to other *elevated* sessions of the same user**).
- **By default, elevated vs. non-elevated sessions do *not* share drive mappings**, so that *no* drive mappings initially exist in an elevated session.

  - However, **with *extra configuration* you can make both types of sessions for a given user *share* mappings**, which *does* allow you to establish (both persistent and non-persistent) mappings from an elevated session that are visible to the same user's non-elevated sessions too  - see [Mapped drives are not available from an elevated prompt when UAC is configured to Prompt for credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drives-not-available-from-elevated-command).

---

As an aside:

Your [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive) command shows the use of ***both* `-Persist` and `-Scope Global`**, which is **indeed required to successfully establish a persistent drive *from a script*** (from a scope other than the global one, i.e. other than directly from the interactive prompt).

**If you use `-Persist` *alone*, it is *quietly ignored***: that is, a non-persistent, scope-local PowerShell-only drive is established.

Given that establishing a persistent drive mapping is unrelated to PowerShell's scopes, and that a successfully established persistent drive (or a non-persistent one established with `net use` or from File Explorer) is by definition visible in *all* PowerShell scopes, **there should be *no* need to also specify `-Scope Global`** - unfortunately, it was decided not to fix this usability problem: see [GitHub issue #15752](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15752).

Comment: The `New-PSDrive` docs never talk about other users or shells anyway. `-Scope Global` means the drive will be visible outside the local scope - the script

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, but I just wanted to point that out explicitly. Also, that running as the _same_ user, but _with elevation_ does _not_ work, is far from obvious. That needing to _also_ use `-Global` with `-Persist`  in scripts makes no sense, given that the former is related to PowerShell scopes, whereas the latter is an unrelated, system concept applying to a user's OS session as a whole. Sadly, they decided not to fix that; see [GitHub issue #15752](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15752).

Comment: It is, if you remember that Administrator sessions are isolated themselves. Which I always remember *after* something fails

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for a lot of useful information. But I'm still looking for a simple solution that from a UX point of view should be obvious, i.e. any mapped network drive/share that is created from that user login session, is expected to be accessible from all shells and file browsers etc. (Just like creating any old folder would be.) `How can I make this work?`

Comment: @not2qubit, you can't achieve this _across different user accounts_. In order to establish persistent mappings for multiple users, you'll probably have to use GPOs, as described [here](https://activedirectorypro.com/map-network-drives-with-group-policy/).