# pass arguments to the Start-Process script block

Tags: powershell, start-process

Trying to run simple http server in separate process using powershell. But can't figure out how to pass parameters to it. Tried several approaches and constantly getting exception. Could you advice?

```
$port = 9700
$prefix = 'http://+:{0}/' -f $port;  

 $ScriptBlock = {

    $http = [System.Net.HttpListener]::new() 
    $http.Prefixes.Add($args[0]); 
    $http.Start(); 
    $Error.Clear(); }


Start-Process pwsh -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-NoExit',  "-Command" $ScriptBlock $prefix -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

In result of example above it:
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '      $http = [System.Net.HttpListener]::new()
| $http.Prefixes.Add($args[0]);      $http.Start();      $Error.Clear(); '.

Comment: You can't pass a ```ScriptBlock``` *object* as an argument to ```Start-Process```. You'll need to serialize your commands into a string and pass that in the argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- All pass-through arguments passed to [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) must be the elements of a *single array* passed to `-ArgumentList`.

  - `$ScriptBlock` and `$prefix` in your call aren't part of the `-ArgumentList` array and therefore constitute additional, *positional* arguments from `Start-Process`'s perspective, which it doesn't recognize - that caused the error you saw.
- Fundamentally, all pass-through arguments are invariably *strings*, so you cannot pass a *script block* as such (it would be turned into its verbatim source code, not including the enclosing `{` and `}`)

However, since are looking for *synchronous* invocation (`-Wait`) in the *same window* (`-NoNewWindow`), **there's no need for `Start-Process` at all, and you can simply call `pwsh` directly**, which - from *inside* a PowerShell session ony - *does* allow you to use a script block:

```bash
pwsh -NoProfile -NoExit $ScriptBlock -args $prefix
```

See the docs for PowerShell (Core)'s CLI, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh).

---

**If you do want to use `Start-Process`** - which is only necessary if you want to run the code in a *new window* or *with elevation* (as admin) or *with a different user identity* - use the following:

- For readability and ease of embedding quotes, the solution uses an expandable [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>@"`).
- It takes advantage of the fact that script blocks serialize as their verbatim source code, excluding `{` and `}`, so you make the target PowerShell instance invoke it by enclosing it in `& { ... }` in the command string.

  - While `& { $ScriptBlock }` would work in your particular case, to make the technique *robust*, any embedded `"` characters must be escaped as `\"`-escaped in order to ensure that the CLI's initial command-line parsing doesn't remove them.
    This is what the `-replace '(?<!\\)(\\*)"', '$1$1\"'` operation below does.

```bash
Start-Process pwsh @"
-NoProfile -Command & { $($ScriptBlock -replace '(?<!\\)(\\*)"', '$1$1\"') } "$prefix"
"@
```

Note:

- *All* pass-through arguments for `pwsh` are encoded in a *single string* passed to the (positionally implied) `-ArgumentList` parameter.

  - While passing pass-through arguments *individually* - as the elements of an *array*, as you originally tried - may be conceptually preferable, a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) unfortunately makes the single-string approach preferable, because it makes the situational need for *embedded* double-quoting explicit - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271756/45375).
- While you could alternatively make use of the `-EncodedCommand` and (currently undocumented) `-EncodedArguments` CLI parameters, doing is even more cumbersome, due to requiring Base64 encoding.

  - In *direct* invocation, as shown in the first snippet, PowerShell actually makes use of these parameters *behind the scenes*, which makes invocation convenient - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74228152/45375) for background information.
- If you do want to use these parameters with `Start-Process`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75560856/45375) for an example.